# Fragment on Button Click Open Activity Load it with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Image below is want I want**

[image]

> The `MainActivity` has a Fragment, in which there are 3 Buttons.
>
> On Click of Button the Container should load the particular Fragment
>
> `ContainerActivity` should load the `Fragment`
>
> i have created three fragment
>   studyfragment, mathsfragment, sciencefragment

I have tried below code, but not working.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(First.this.getActivity(),Container.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Second second = new Second();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.cont,second).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Try removing this : `First.this.getActivity()` and replace it with: `getActivity()`. Also, are you asking to when a `Button` clicked, it should show multiple `Fragment` & Activities? Because your codes show that when the `Button` clicked, it should go to Container class and then replace a `Fragment` !!

Comment: the code does not really match the concept, which by itself already uses messy names for the `Activity` & `Fragment` classes. the `Intent` most likely should be `Intent(MainActivity.this, ContainerActivity.class);` with a `Bundle` of intent-extras passed, so one can inflate the according fragment. can provide a hint, but won't do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

It does not actually match the concept of what you showed in the picture but, to do so, handle the `Button` like this:

```
Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Container.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        // First go to container class-Activity

    }
});
```

Then, in the container class-`Activity`, show the `Fragment`:

```
Second second = new Second();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.cont, second).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

<sub>Note that it should be placed inside `onCreate()` method to show the `Fragment`.</sub>

Comment: But on Particular Button click it will not show my required fragement